# How can I rerender a component in react if window.location- changes?

Tags: reactjs, url, react-helmet

I have a React component, that should re-render, when `window.location.href` changes. This component uses react-helmet and I use it to update the title of the application.

I know I could do it with a page refresh but since only the anchor changes, I don't want the entire page to reloads but just the component that changes the title with `react-helment`.

Versions:

- react: 18.2.0
- react-helmet: 6.1.0

**Edit:**
I use i18next and if I use `window.addEventListener('popstate',` I got the error message `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Answer (score 0):

React components rerender when state changes. You can store the title in the component state using the useState hook and update the state when window.location.href changes. In this way the component will rerender.